# Any Example of WebJob using EventHub?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub, azure-webjobssdk

I've tried to come up with something from the example in the WebJobsSDK gitHub

```
var eventHubConfig = new EventHubConfiguration();
string eventHubName = "MyHubName";
eventHubConfig.AddSender(eventHubName,"Endpoint=sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SendRule;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxx");
eventHubConfig.AddReceiver(eventHubName, "Endpoint=sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ReceiveRule;SharedAccessKey=yyyyyyy");

config.UseEventHub(eventHubConfig);
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```

But I'm afraid that's not far enough for someone of my limited "skillset"!

- I can find no instance of JobHostConfiguration that has a UseEventHub property (using the v1.2.0-alpha-10291 version of the Microsoft.AzureWebJobs package), so I can't pass the EventHubConfiguration to the JobHost.
- I've used EventHub before, not within the WebJob context. I don't see if the EventHostProcessor is still required if using the WebJob triggering...or does the WebJob trigger essentially act as the EventHostProcessor?

Anyway, if anyone has a more complete example for a simpleton like me that would be really sweet! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support), you should have all the information you need.

What you are missing is a reference of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.1.2.0-alpha-10291` nuget package.

The `UseEventHub` is an extension method that is declared in this package.

Otherwise your configuration seems ok.
Here is an example on how to receive or send messages from/to an EventHub:

```
public class BasicTest
{
    public class Payload
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
    public static void SendEvents([EventHub("MyHubName")] out Payload x)
    {
        x = new Payload { Counter = 100 };
    }

    public static void Trigger(
        [EventHubTrigger("MyHubName")] Payload x,
        [EventHub("MyHubName")] out Payload y)
    {
        x.Counter++;
        y = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I was using that nuget package and following that rather 'light' example. I didn't see the extension method so once I added a "using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" I could at least get it to compile. I'm still a ways from anything actually working though. As I mentioned, that example is a little oversimplified for my skills.

Comment: @WirelessG, feel free to edit your question or ask a new one if you need more detail on implemting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

EventProcessorHost is still required, as the WebJob just provides the hosting environment for running it. As far as I know, EventProcessorHost is not integrated so deeply into WebJob, so its triggering mechanism cannot be used for processing EventHub messages. I use WebJob for running EventProcessorHost continuously:

```
public static void Main()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}

private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (var shutdownWatcher = new WebJobsShutdownWatcher())
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Initializing...");

            var eventProcessorHostName = "eventProcessorHostName";
            var eventHubName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eventHubName"];
            var consumerGroupName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eventHubConsumerGroupName"];
            var eventHubConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventHub"].ConnectionString;
            var storageConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventHubStorage"].ConnectionString;

            var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(eventProcessorHostName, eventHubName, consumerGroupName, eventHubConnectionString, storageConnectionString);

            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Registering event processors...");

            var processorOptions = new EventProcessorOptions();

            processorOptions.ExceptionReceived += ProcessorOptions_ExceptionReceived;

            await eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<CustomEventProcessor>(processorOptions);

            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Processing...");

            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, shutdownWatcher.Token);

            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Unregistering event processors...");

            await eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync();

            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Finished.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleErrorAsync(ex);
        }
    }
}

private static async void ProcessorOptions_ExceptionReceived(object sender, ExceptionReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    await HandleErrorAsync(e.Exception);
}

private static async Task HandleErrorAsync(Exception ex)
{
    await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync($"Critical error occured: {ex.Message}{ex.StackTrace}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Attila, I've done it that way before,  but I think in the new pre-release of azure-webjobs-sdk it's supposed be more deeply integrated. Using the Trigger mechanism in a similar way to webjobs with ServiceBus...I just can't figure it out from the wiki. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support

Comment: I've run into this kind of hosting issue recently too, but I had just found [Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions), which does not deal with EventHub at all. My main concern with the [WebJob SDK EventHub support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support) is its automatic checkpointing after processing messages: a) in high throughput scenarios it might degrade performance; b) how to retry processing messages after a temporary processing failure (eg.: permanent storage is not available).

Comment: The new [EventHubTrigger] attribute (in the service bus extension) will handle the listening for you. It will create an EventProcessHost.  For checking-pointing, you can receive a  batch of events (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support ) and the checkpoint is called once for the whole batch.