# Using EventHub from WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to use EventHub from a WebJob as described https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support and [Any Example of WebJob using EventHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727808/any-example-of-webjob-using-eventhub/37679566#37679566).

The problem is that the SO question refers to the nuget package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.1.2.0-alpha-10291 and as far as I can see, that package isn't available anymore.

Does anybody know if there's a new release in the pipe or any other workaround?

BR,
Max.

Answer (score 0):

That library is available from [MyGet repository](https://www.myget.org/feed/azure-appservice/package/nuget/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/1.2.0-alpha-10291) and is being updated sometimes. For adding that, you need to add that repository to NuGet settings:

Package Manager Settings => create a new package source => Use https://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/ as a link for the repository.

Now, you should have the library and its dependencies.